# Drawing image on canvas in loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
wheel = canvas.getContext("2d");          
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var img = new Image;
  img.src = image;
  wheel.drawImage(img, -170, -10, 140, 140);
}
```

My above code draw only 9(Nine) images but lastOne(10th) image not drawing on canvas. I tried above code but not getting success. Anyone can know solution for this problem.

> Can any one help me to find out online **JSFiddle Demo** which draw image on canvas in loop.

Comment: can you create a fiddle example for your problem so that we can check and rectify

Comment: What makes you think the 10th element is not drawn? Where do you set `image`? It would really help us to see a more complete sample of your code

Comment: How do you know there's only nine images? I mean the same image on the same position nine or ten times shouldn't make much difference?

Comment: I will update question after making **JSFiddle** sample code

Comment: Can any one help me to find out jsfiddle which draw image on canvas in loop.

Comment: You for loop says: from 0 to less than 10. Perhaps you cut of too early? try `for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {`

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen I tried that also but last two images are blank.

Comment: Can't you just show your real code? Most likely you've an incorrect src stored for the last image (or not have it stored at all), or it is positioned off-canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your image isn't finished loading before your first draw attempt.

Here is the syntax to make sure your image has finished loading:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.width = 1100;
canvas.height = 110;
var wheel = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    wheel.drawImage(img, 5 + 110 * i, 5);
  }
};
img.src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=1&w=100&h=100";
```

**EDIT 1 - PROMISES**

Working with multiple images:

1. List sources
2. `map` to generates DOM nodes
3. Setup a `Promise` per DOM node in a `Promise.all`
4. Then draw images

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.width = 1100;
canvas.height = 110;
var wheel = canvas.getContext("2d");
var images = [
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=1&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=2&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=3&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=4&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=5&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=6&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=7&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=8&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=9&w=100&h=100",
    "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=10&w=100&h=100",
  ]
  .map(function(i) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = i;
    return img;
  });
Promise.all(images.map(function(image) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      image.onload = resolve;
    });
  }))
  .then(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var img = images[i];
      wheel.drawImage(img, 5 + 110 * i, 5);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do the similar approach to Emil, only difference having a method that loads them individually and once the image is loaded, try to load the next one and so on ...

take a look:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

// setting canvas size
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 10;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 10;

var image_test = document.querySelector(".hidden");
var count = 0;
var total_images = 10;
var wheel = canvas.getContext("2d");      
function loadImage() { 
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() { 
    wheel.drawImage( this , 105 * count , 0 , 100, 100);
    if( count < total_images ) { 
        count++;
      loadImage();
    }
  }
  // img.src = "image-" + count + ".jpg";
  img.src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=1&w=100&h=100";
}
loadImage();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gugalondon/r5xw6u7L/7